# Is it possible to disable ctrl + a in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I want to disable the command ctrl + a (select all) in Access 2007. Is that possible?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'll move this post.

Comment: How is this not a programming question? Sure, you might use a Macro for this, but Macros are a form of programming. I'd do it in code, myself (instead of in an AutoKeys macro that just disables it), as I'd likely want to disable it only in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and it is possible by code :)

[se this answer from superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/73868/is-it-possible-to-disable-ctrl-a-in-access-2007/74062#74062)